# Submenu hover display restriction

Tags: html, css, menu, drupal-8

I have a problem with a personal project, http://mail.fixca.com.gt/.  on Drupal 8 with the profile Brainstorm

The menu doesn't display the submenus created. I have already:

- Set Show Expanded mode on the menu item.
- Set the max menu level display on the block it self.
- Tried to create a new menu and CSS it to get it display the submenu

  .submenu{
          display:none;
      }

  .companymenuli:hover > ul{
          display:block;
      }

but it never shows the submenu. I realise that it might be something I'm just not doing right, but I cann't find the solution.

The HTML on the Drupals Website shows like this

[HTML from chrome developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4L2A.png)

I think that it might be some kind of restriction on the theme itself.

I really appreciate your help. If you have give mi a hint on where I might be able to find the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow: hidden. is added in below css:

```
#block-brainstorm-theme-main-menu
```

Once you remove overflow property from here and also remove display: none. from

```
#block-brainstorm-theme-main-menu ul ul
```

Submenu will display. But you have to work on css and js for proper look and feel. Instead I suggest to use some jquery for this.Also you can use modules like Nice menu or Superfish menu for the same. Let me know if i can help you in this.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped a lot. I'm actually learning. So, i was able to fix it with your tip. Now I want to be able to hover the submenu. but i can make it to stick arround, [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD22H04IZIM6), im able to replicate it, but because of the nav format, i guess, i cant use the statement (ul a:hover ul) it only works with (ul a:hover + ul). Any help?